# Adding DataTables plugin to Shiny app

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I would like to add [time plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/time) (yes, I know it is deprecated) to a Shiny app. For existing plugins procedure seems to be trivial - just [copy `js` file to a `datatables-plugins` directory](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/764039c9c6b3530d263c2826f660bfe33b30781e/tools/update_DT.R#L92-L95) so I copied plugin to the `DT` installation directory:

```
tree DT/htmlwidgets/lib/datatables-plugins
DT/htmlwidgets/lib/datatables-plugins
├── natural
│   └── natural.js
├── searchHighlight
│   ├── dataTables.searchHighlight.css
│   ├── dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js
│   └── jquery.highlight.js
└── time
    └── time.js

3 directories, 5 files
```

but when I try a simple app:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        data.frame(x = c("7:10", "10:21", "80:12")),
        plugins = 'time', options = list(
        dom = 't',
        columnDefs = list(list(type = 'time-uni', targets = 1))
      ))
    })
  }
)
```

It looks like plugin is detected correctly (no error compared to non existing plugin) but it doesn't change sorting order (descending order shown below):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables plug-ins are client-side JavaScript, so you'll have to enable client-side processing to use any of them with `DT` in Shiny (render with `server = FALSE`).

https://rstudio.github.io/DT/plugins.html

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        data.frame(x = c("7:10", "10:21", "80:12")),
        plugins = 'time', options = list(
          dom = 't',
          columnDefs = list(list(type = 'time-uni', targets = 1))
        ))
    }, server = FALSE)
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you once again! _note the plug-ins for filtering and sorting may not work for server-side processing, e.g. when you render tables in Shiny_  should be emphasized in the documentation.